# how to lower case the value of unique:true keys in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have created a mongodb and by mistake have entered duplicate values in the form of capital and small case letters.

I have made the index unique. MongoDB is case sensitive and hence, considered the capital letter and small letter as different values.

Now my problem is the database have got around 32 GB. and I came across this issue. Kindly help me.

Here is the sample:

```
db.tt.createIndex({'email':1},{unique:true})

> db.tt.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591d706c0ef9acde11d7af66"),
        "email" : "g@gmail.com",
        "src" : [
                {
                        "acc" : "ln"
                },
                {
                        "acc" : "drb"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591d70740ef9acde11d7af68"),
        "email" : "G@gmail.com",
        "src" : [
                {
                        "acc" : "ln"
                },
                {
                        "acc" : "drb"
                },
                {
                        "acc" : "dd"
                }
        ]
}
```

How I can make the `email` as lowercase and assign the src values to the original one. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you want to merge both documents into single one?

Comment: yes exactly, you can see that the emails is common.. only capital and small. Even the record with src is `"acc": "dd"` is only new. So merging and making the email proper. all to small letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achive this using **`$toLower`** aggregation operator like this :

```
    db.tt.aggregate([  
   {  
      $project:{  
         email:{  
            $toLower:"$email"
         },
         src:1
      }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:"$src"
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$email",
         src:{  
            $addToSet:"$src"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $project:{  
         _id:0,
         email:"$_id",
         src:1
      }
   },
   {  
      $out:"anotherCollection"
   }
])
```

**`$addToSet`** allow to keep oly one distinct occurence of `src` items

this will write this document to a new collection named `anotherCollection`:

```
{ "email" : "g@gmail.com", "src" : [ { "acc" : "dd" }, { "acc" : "drb" }, { "acc" : "ln" } ] }
```

Note that with **`$out`**, you can averwrite directly your `tt` collection, however before doing this make sure to understand what your doing because all previous data will be lost

Comment: How to update or remove the entry of the capital data?

Comment: @JafferWilson no, this won't update or remove any document. Tou may loop over the results to save them, or write them directly using the **`$out`** operator at the end of the aggregation pipeline

Comment: can you please update your answer and show me how I can write it to another mongodb or to file.. please

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I can think of to merge the data is run an aggregation and loop the result to write back to the collection in bulk operations:

```
var ops = [];

db.tt.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$src" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$toLower": "$email" },
    "src": { "$addToSet": "$src" },
    "ids": { "$addToSet": "$_id" }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  var id = doc.ids.shift();
  ops = [
    ...ops,
    {
      "deleteMany": {
        "filter": { "_id": { "$in": doc.ids } }
      }
    },
    { 
      "updateOne": { 
        "filter": { "_id": id },
        "update": { 
          "$set": { "email": doc._id },
          "$addToSet": { "src": { "$each": doc.src } }
        }
      }
    },
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.tt.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }

});

if ( ops.length > 0 )
    db.tt.bulkWrite(ops);
```

In steps, that's `$unwind` the array items so they can be merged via `$addToSet`, under a `$group` on using `$toLower` on the `email` value. You also want to keep the set of unique source document ids.

In the loop you `shift` the first `_id` value off of `doc.ids` and update that document with the lowercase email and the revised "src" set. Using `$addToSet` here makes the operation write safe with any other updates that might occur to the document.

Then the other operation in the loop deletes the other documents that shared the same converted case email, so there are no duplicates. Actually do that one first. The default "ordered" operations make sure this is fine.

And do it in the shell, since it's a one-off operation and is really just as simple as listing as shown.

Comment: I am getting Memory issue with your solution. Can you tell me what I need to do? Even if I try to use `allowDiskUse:true` still storage issues remains. How I can modify the storage of temporary files for the program?

Comment: @JafferWilson What is the error you are receiving if any? Is this coming from the `.aggregate()` or other code?

Comment: No it is from the aggregate function. The RAM issue.

Comment: see this is the error: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/42cc169c06f1fd418a7483a1b1ac4ac7

Comment: And the process is damn slow.

Comment: @JafferWilson Okay. The main thing is that it's not the BSON limit. Just for arguments sake, why don't we separate the concerns here and try and add an `$out` stage to write to another collection. Then you can do the update loop by reading from the target collection instead of the cursor output. Also are you sure you set `allowDiskUse: true` correctly

Comment: @JafferWilson At 32GB and if your RAM is not at least sitting around that level, then anything is not going to be real fast.

Comment: Yes tried something like this: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/e4ae05a7a327997cab4d47f95d9575dc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144830/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-neil-lunn).